# Silverlight with RIA services

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I am currently researching RIA services with Silverlight.

We are not interested in using EF as we are using a MDA framework (www.capableobjects.com) which seems to do more than EF.

I was wondering if it is at all possible to plug in our model to benefit from RIA services? Would we have to create a POCO model and from that update our model from the services exposed from the POCO classes?

JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Brad Abrams' [26 part introduction to RIA services](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/08/02/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-summary.aspx). He includes details on several back-end data abstractions outside of what RIA services gives you out of the box including: LinqToSql, POCO, NHibernate, and WCF services. Hopefully one of these examples will give you the reference material you need for your specific framework.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I see a POCO setup but cannot seem to get it building on my machine. I will have to do some more research.

Comment: Downloaded the demo from Brads intro to RIA and I get the following error:
Error 1 The TypeDescriptionProvider 'System.Web.DomainServices.LinqToEntities.LinqToEntitiesTypeDescriptionProvider' specified does not provide a public constructor of one of the supported signatures. MyApp

Comment: Okay, a long day but finally got Poco working. For those who follow Brads articles, remember that they are written with an older version. First I create from scratch an application using Entity framework. The  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2387 walkthrough helped. Then I removed the EF code and the meta and domain service code and basically followed Brads http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/07/22/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-6-poco-and-authentication-provider.aspx.